# Reverse DOM node order with Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom, language-features

I'm curious if there is an easy way to make this transition with JavaScript.

```
<div>
  <i>
    <b>
      TEXT
    </b>
  </i>
</div>
```

To this:

```
<div>
  <b>
    <i>
      TEXT
    </i>
  </b>
</div>
```

Now I know that this is possible in longer ways, like creating a new `<b>` and `<i>`, placing all of old `<b>` inside of new `<i>`, and then new `<i>` inside of the new `<b>`, and then replace the child, or similar method. But I'm curious if there's something like `node.swapTypeWithParent` or `swapNodeTypes(b, i)`.

Comment: However, I don't think this is meaningful. Because element nesting has many constraints - simply "reverse" a valid dom tree may result in an invalid one.

Comment: Append the text node to the `i` node, append the `b` node to the `div`, append the `i` to `b` – that’s about as short as it gets, without creating any new nodes. http://jsfiddle.net/p49shh43/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's not. Presuming by "longer ways" you mean moving and replacing elements and text with javascript, then that's the way to do it and there are no other shortcuts in javascript.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this pretty easily with a couple loops

```
function reverseNest(bottom_level, top_level) {
    var arr = [],
        e = bottom_level,
        f;
    while ((e = e.parentNode) && e !== top_level) {
        arr.push(e);
    }
    arr.push(bottom_level);
    e = top_level || document.documentElement;
    while (arr.length) {
        f = arr.shift();
        e.appendChild(f); // may want to use .insertBefore
        e = f;
    }
}
```

Here, `bottom_level` would be your *#text* node and `top_level` would be your `<div>`

Quick [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/dvprn3Lk/) (inspect with console to see reversed tags)

Answer (score -1):

Here's my jQuery based solution. I think it doesn't get shorter than this!

`$('div>*>*').contents().unwrap();`

`$('div>*').wrap('<b></b>');`

I know your example is just a demo for this feature but I still find it trivial that we're swapping `<i>` elements with `<b>` elements since the result will be the same semantically and stylistically :)